# Head covering a sign of being a bride of HaShem?

Tags: minhag, wedding, commentaries, kippa-yarmulka, hair-covering

Bnei Yisrael’s relationship with HaShem is often described as a marriage; HaShem is the groom and Bnei Yisrael are His bride. See Shir HaShirim for an extended example. The Prophets frequently compared the relationship between Hashem and Israel to the relationship between bridegroom and bride and/or the relationship between husband and wife. For example, regarding the reconciliation of Israel with Hashem, it is written, “As the bridegroom rejoices over the bride, so shall your God rejoice over you” (Isaiah 63:5). And it is also written regarding this reconcilation, “And it shall be on that day, spoke Hashem, that you will call Me, ‘my Husband’ ”(Hosea 2:18). There are many other examples that can be found, but here's my question, although it might be a little far fetched..

If Bnei Yisrael is compared to a bride, and it is the custom for brides to cover their heads, could the headcovering (for woman, when praying for example) be a symbolic sign of being a bride of HaShem (i.e. being a sign of commitment to HaShem; commitment to a covenent/Torah keeping lifestyle)?

Are there any commentaries regarding to this?

Comment: The source for covering the head is Kiddushin 31a that states that one covers the head "since the shekhina is above". The reason doesnt seem to relate to brides.

Comment: Why do you think that it is traditional for brides to cover their heads? Are you referring to veils?

Comment: @mevaqesh History (at least for a large part) shows this was the case yes, that veiling was a custom.

Comment: But covering the head dates back to the Talmud, so you'd have to show historically that it went back to then. Also, that isn't the stated reason in the Talmud.